# newline symbol in qml Textfield, text property not working

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Is there a possibility to insert a newline character into the text property of a TextField component:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Grid {
        TextField {
            text: "Text\nhere"
        }
    }
}
```

prints a blank instead of a newline in the Textfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html):

> TextField is used to accept a line of text input. [...]

Therefore you can not have multiple lines in that item. You must use another item like [TextArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html)

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Grid {
        TextArea {
            text: "Text\nshere"
        }
    }
}
```